# Insert/Update in 2 different databases

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, database

I have a webapp that uses mongoDB and another Database (postgresql) for other app.
When I insert data on mongoDB I need to insert also on postgresql, the databases structures is not the same. The problem is when I insert on both DB and one of them fails, same problem for update. Any clue how could do this the right way?

There are 2 apps:
First app is an administrative site (web) built on java and using mongoDB
and the second app is android app based on the postgresql, the website generate some content save it to mongodb and then send the data using a webservice to the postgresql database.

I know it sounds awful but the website wasn't meant for that purpose at the begin lol.

Comment: please describe the architecture of your app, (language, framework, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform tow phase commit,

[Tow phase commit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)
[MongoDB tow phase commit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/#phase-commits-rollback)

Comment: Could I use 2 phase commit when databases are different? One is mongoDb and the other is postgresql

Comment: yes sure, but first tell me more about the architecture of your application